# How to calculate and substitute values in a specific column of tabular data?

Tags: string, perl, data-structures, awk, substitution

Given the following input:

```
MCCC processed: unknown event at: Tue, 14 Oct 2014 12:02:26 CST 
station, mccc delay,    std,    cc coeff,  cc std,   pol   , t0_times  , delay_times
 ZJ.uno1     -0.7964    0.0051    0.9690    0.0139    0  GRAW.BHZ   301.1263    -1.8041
 ZJ.dose     -0.7065    0.0072    0.9760    0.0133    0  KNYN.BHZ   301.3372    -1.9249
 ZJ.tres      0.9675    0.0072    0.9548    0.0292    0  LEON.BHZ   301.2611    -0.1749
Phase: P        
PDE    2013  7 15 14  6 58.00   -60.867   -25.143   31.0  0.0  7.3
```

I want to remove the mean of the 9th column (delay_times) from each of those delay_times, which requires summing the 9th column values, dividing by the number of those values, and then subtracting the mean from each of those values (-1.8041, -1.9249, -0.1749).

I am confused about where to begin this endeavor.  I've provided a starting script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $file '<', "file.txt" or die $!;

while (<$file>) {
    my ($name, $time) = (split /\s+/, $file)[1,9];
 # Calculate the mean of the 9th column for every row that begins with ZJ,
 # and subtract the mean from each value (time) in the 9th column.
}

# Output the new file with the mean removed from each "time" in the 9th column
```

Would this be easier to do in awk, or perl?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempted perl solution is pretty much spot on - you just didn't finish it :-)

An "extended one liner" could be as follows:

```
perl -anE 'push @f,[@F] }{ for (@f){ $s += $_->[8] and $n++ if $_->[0] =~ /ZJ/ } 
           say $_->[0] =~ /ZJ/ ? ( "@{$_}[0..7] ", $_->[8]-($s/$n) ) : "@$_" 
           for @f'  data.txt
```

Slightly shortened by using `-an` (see [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)) but not very golfish. Much as with the `awk` solution from @John1024 we read the file twice - in this case with two `for` loops.  We use a ternary operator (`<cond> ? :`) to print out - or `say` - each lines, either as is (`@$_`), or with the field substitution.

**Output**:

```
MCCC processed: unknown event at: Tue, 14 Oct 2014 12:02:26 CST
station, mccc delay, std, cc coeff, cc std, pol , t0_times , delay_times
ZJ.uno1 -0.7964 0.0051 0.9690 0.0139 0 GRAW.BHZ 301.1263 -0.5028
ZJ.dose -0.7065 0.0072 0.9760 0.0133 0 KNYN.BHZ 301.3372 -0.6236
ZJ.tres 0.9675 0.0072 0.9548 0.0292 0 LEON.BHZ 301.2611 1.1264
Phase: P
PDE 2013 7 15 14 6 58.00 -60.867 -25.143 31.0 0.0 7.3
```

As a script that might read as follows:

```
use v5.16;

my (@timedata, $rec, $sum, $n) ;

while (<DATA>) {
    push @timedata, [ split(" ") ] ;
}

foreach my $rec (@timedata){ 
  $sum += $rec->[8] and $n++ if $rec->[0] =~ /ZJ/ ;
}    

foreach $rec (@timedata) {
 say $rec->[0] =~ /ZJ/  ?  ( "@{$rec}[0..7] ", $rec->[8]-($sum/$n) ) 
                        :    "@$rec" ;
}

__DATA__
MCCC processed: unknown event at: Tue, 14 Oct 2014 12:02:26 CST 
station, mccc delay,  std,   cc coeff,  cc std,   pol   , t0_times  , delay_times
 ZJ.uno1  -0.7964    0.0051    0.9690    0.0139    0  GRAW.BHZ   301.1263 -1.8041
 ZJ.dose  -0.7065    0.0072    0.9760    0.0133    0  KNYN.BHZ   301.3372 -1.9249
 ZJ.tres   0.9675    0.0072    0.9548    0.0292    0  LEON.BHZ   301.2611 -0.1749
Phase: P        
PDE    2013  7 15 14  6 58.00   -60.867   -25.143   31.0  0.0  7.3
```

There may well be a way to avoid the two loops (combining `while` or `map` with `for` wouldn't really count though), but creating the  sum and average in one pass and substituting in another makes the script clear and simple.

Comment: Hello G.Cito,

Thanks for your comments.  I'm going to take a look at this script and I'll let you know if I have any trouble.  Thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '/Phase/{f=0} FNR==NR && f{s+=$9;n++;} /station/{f=1} FNR==NR{next;} FNR==1{ave=s/n} f{$9=$9-ave} 1' file file
MCCC processed: unknown event at: Tue, 14 Oct 2014 12:02:26 CST 
station, mccc delay, std, cc coeff, cc std, 1.3013 , t0_times , delay_times
ZJ.uno1 -0.7964 0.0051 0.9690 0.0139 0 GRAW.BHZ 301.1263 -0.5028
ZJ.dose -0.7065 0.0072 0.9760 0.0133 0 KNYN.BHZ 301.3372 -0.6236
ZJ.tres 0.9675 0.0072 0.9548 0.0292 0 LEON.BHZ 301.2611 1.1264
Phase: P        
PDE    2013  7 15 14  6 58.00   -60.867   -25.143   31.0  0.0  7.3
```

#### How it works

Because the name of the file appears twice on the command line, this program reads through the file twice.  The first time, it stores the sum of the column 9 numbers in `s` and the number of column 9 numbers in `n`.  Thus the average is `s/n`.  On the second time through, it subtracts the average from the column 9 value and prints the lines.

As I interpret the question, the column 9 values of interest appear to be the ones after the line that starts with `station` and before the line that starts with `Phase`.  We keep and update a flag `f` to signal when we are in the range of lines of interest.

- `/Phase/{f=0}`

  When we have reached the line with `Phase`, set flag `f` to false to signal that we have reached the end of the range of lines.
- `FNR==NR && f{s+=$9;n++;}`

  On the first time reading through the file and if flag `f` is true, then update the sum `s` and count `n`.

  In awk, `FNR` is the number of lines read so far from the current file and `NR` is the total number of lines read.  Thus, if `FNR==NR`, we are still reading the first file.
- `/station/{f=1}`

  If we are on the line with `station`, then set flag `f` to true to signal the beginning of the lines of interest.
- `FNR==NR{next;}`

  If we are reading the file the first time, skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `FNR==1{ave=s/n}`

  If we have gotten here, we are now reading the file the second time.  When we get to the first line (`FNR==1`) of this second read through, calculate the average `ave`.
- `f{$9=$9-ave}`

  If `f` is true, subtract the average, `ave`, from column 9, `$9`.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic short hand for print-the-line.

Comment: Hi John,  Thanks for your help.  I was wondering if you could make sense of the one-line awk code you've provided?  First with "Phase" and "station", are you essentially setting boundaries for where awk should be reading in the 9th column?  I'm slightly confused with your FNR==NR statements.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user78872 I have added an explanation for that to the answer.

Comment: Hi John,  
I am running your one-liner inside a bash script, because I want to perform this for multiple files.  The code I have is below:

`#!/bin/bash

for i in `ls *mcp`; do

awk '/Mean/{f=0} FNR==NR && f{s+=$9;n++;} /station/{f=1} FNR==NR{next;} FNR==1{ave=s/n} f{$9=$9-ave} 1' $i $i  >> $i.newmcp

done`

I want to output to a new *mcp file, with the same formatting.  When I run the one-liner you have provided above, the formatting changes, such as there aren't spaces where there need to be.  Without doing any sort of printf command, is there a way to maintain the original formatting?

Comment: _"such as there aren't spaces where there need to be."_  Where do there need to be spaces?

Comment: ++ ... must ... learn .... tricky awk  powers - and morph these powers in order to improve my perl skills ;-)

Comment: What I mean is, when I want to read this file into perl, for example, the rows beginning with ZJ all move to the left one space.  So, if I read this into perl, now the column that I perform the operation on ($9), becomes column 8.  Could I use a printf command to fix this?